# Nokia Lumia 520 Internet Sharing Problem

Tags: lumia, internet-sharing

I set up my Nokia Lumia 520 as a Wifi Spot turning on Internet Sharing.

When I'm connecting from my notebook to Nokia Lumia Wifi Spot it is connecting just fine, but in the Chrome or Firefox I get ssl certificate error.

My date+time are set to automatically on the phone.

Can you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with the laptop, than the phone. You *might* get a better response over on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). A certificate error can indicate a "man in the middle" attack, but it's more likely that would be happening with malware/adware on the laptop, rather than the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Please **Reinstall** your Program that is **Firefox/Chrome**. It May Solve Your Problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this following ;

Activate your mobile data and you will get the access point at the end of the settings app, in that create a new access point with the right APN and at the end in authentication , Type select CHAP and save the settings.

Now activate the newly created setting and use in your laptop and ipad,etc..